# How do I create a patch for each of my commits in git?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I already have my commits. How do I create patches from them? I tried to do

```
git format-patch mybranchname.patch
```

or something like that, I don't remember the exact command, but what it did is basically create one patch with the latest commit, but I need to create multiple patches, because I have multiple commits. How do I create a patch for each of my commits?

Answer (score 7):

The syntax for `git format-patch` is described [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-format-patch). To create a patch per commit between commits *R1* and *R2*, use the following:

```
git format-patch R1..R2
```

This will create one file per commit in the local directory.

Example:

```
$ git log --oneline
190f82d I Remember Nothing
3b29748 Interzone
28f44ed Wilderness
e8c9ace Shadowplay
088991e She's Lost Control
878ccfa New Dawn Fades
5191dbf Insight
e81746f Candidate
0fb8338 Day of the Lords
57293e8 Disorder
```

Let's say you want to create patches for the commits "Candidate" through "I Remember Nothing". You take the two commit hashes and use them to define the commit range:

```
$ git format-patch e81746f..190f82d
```

This will generate 8 patch files in the current directory, one for each commit.

Comment: If I have 6 commits, does that mean it would be R1...R6?

Comment: Also, if I try that it says unknown revision or path not in the working tree.

Comment: Yes, you would use the commit hashes, e.g. From git log. Can you update your question with the output of git log --oneline and the patch command?

Comment: It gives me a 7 digit code and then the message that I wrote for each commit.

Comment: These 7 digit code are what you have to use in the format-patch command.